# Recursive MergeSort

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 

public class Main {
    public static void merge(int[]arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
        int temp[] = new int[high + 1];
        int index = 0;
        int left = low;
        int right = mid + 1;
        while (left <= mid && right <= high) {
            if (arr[left] <= arr[right]) {
                temp[index] = arr[left];
                left++;
            } else {
                temp[index] = arr[right];
                right++;
            }
            index++;
        }
        //for exhaustion of any of the parts
        while (left <= mid ){
            temp[index] = arr[left];
            left++;
            index++;
        }
        while (right <= high ){
            temp[index] = arr[right];
            right++;
            index++;
        }
        //copying elements to array
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = temp[i];
        }
        //printing arr
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void mergesort(int[]arr, int low, int high) {
        //base case
        if (low >= high) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        mergesort(arr, low, mid);
        mergesort(arr, mid + 1, high);
        merge(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 2, 3, 46, 5, 8, 7, 6 };
        int n = arr.length;
        mergesort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    }
}
```

I implemented `mergesort` using recursion, please help identify what's wrong with my code? It is giving first three elements sorted then some 0s and then again sorted elements and then unsorted.

Recursion not working properly and giving sorted array results why?

Comment: Too bad that you are a member for more than two years, but without any trace so far. Is this question going to last? Or will it be deleted once answered?

Comment: Find the smallest data set which reproduces the problem, and step through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix (there may be other issues):

```
    int temp [] = new int[high-low+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //copying elements to array
        for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
            arr[i]=temp[i];
        }
```

Is copying back into the original array starting at `0` instead of `low`. And also copying all of `temp`, not just the portion of it that you're populating during that call.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in the code:

- `int temp[] = new int[high + 1];` defines a temporary array that is way too large. It should be:

  ```
    int temp[] = new int[high - low + 1];
  ```
- the loop to copy the temporary array back to the original array is incorrect too: the destination index should be offset by `low` entries:

  ```
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            arr[low + i] = temp[i];
        }
  ```